# i can´t plot sphere function in matlab, what can i do it?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot this sphere function http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/spheref.html

Authors: Sonja Surjanovic, Simon Fraser University

```
%          Derek Bingham, Simon Fraser University

INPUT:
%
% xx = [x1, x2, ..., xd]
%


d = length(xx);
sum = 0;
for ii = 1:d
    xi = xx(ii);
    sum = sum + xi^2;
end

y = sum;

end
```

but I don't understand what  I need to do, because the function returns a sum, it is just one number, but to plot in 3d we need 3 arguments.
And the vector what type of arguments describe?

Comment: already did but does not answer

Answer (score 1):

This function `f(x)` is just used to define only one point in n-dimension space. For example, to define sphere you can use equation `f(xx)=3^2`, where `xx=[x1,x2,x3]`, `3` is the sphere radius.

To plot a sphere with unit radius consisting of 20-by-20 faces in MATLAB you can use

```
figure
sphere
```

Or if your want to plot sphere with radius `radius` centered at `(x0,y0,z0)` consisting of 100-by-100 faces

```
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(100); % 100 is the number for faces
x0 = 5;
y0 = 6;
z0 = 7; 
radius = 3;
surf(radius*X-x0, radius*Y-y0, radius*Z-z0)
```